# Using port.emit and port.on in a firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

Can someone please explain the context in which port.on and port.emit are used in a firefox extension?

From the [official documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html) I imagine that this should work:

```
//main.js
var someData = "Message received"; 

self.port.emit("myMessage", someData);
self.port.on("myMessage", alert(someData));
```

but I get

> Error: self is not defined.

After attaching this to a defined object like this:

```
var self = require("sdk/self"); 
self.port.emit("myMessage", someData);
```

I get

> Error: port is not defined.

Comment: Read the documentation again. Did you know that `main.js` is not a content script, but a kind of background script?

Comment: I did know that, does port.emit only work with content scripts?

Comment: No. A [worker port](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/content/worker.html#port) is just an event emitter. See docs for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the page-mod module to inject a content script into a web page, you then use self.port in the content script to communicate back with main.js. For example:

main.js:

```
var data = require('sdk/self').data;

require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
  include: ["*"],
  contentScriptFile: [data.url('cs.js')],
  attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.emit('attached', true);
  }
});
```

cs.js:

```
self.port.on('attached', function() {
  console.log('attached...');
});
```

For the related documentation, start here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts